# Add filter to Admin list for all custom post types by their custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, post-type

I want to add **filter** on every **Custom post type** that have taxonomy associated with it.

I have googled but found code for only for single post type or for single taxonomy.

Comment: http://www.makarandmane.com/?p=1010

Answer (score 1):

I found a code which work only with single taxonomy and modified it.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_restrict_manage_posts' );

function my_restrict_manage_posts() {
    global $typenow, $post, $post_id;

    if( $typenow != "page" && $typenow != "post" ){
        //get post type
        $post_type=get_query_var('post_type'); 

        //get taxonomy associated with current post type
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);

        //in next loop add filter for tax
        if ($taxonomies) {
            foreach ($taxonomies as $tax_slug) {
                $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);
                echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform'>";
                echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
                foreach ($terms as $term) { 
                    $label = (isset($_GET[$tax_slug])) ? $_GET[$tax_slug] : ''; // Fix
                    echo '<option value='. $term->slug, $label == $term->slug ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>' . $term->name .' (' . $term->count .')</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you can use easier `wp_dropdown_categories` to generate the dropdown from a taxonomy.